# Toggle my menu when you click my nav button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I am trying to achieve is when I click on my `<div>` class "menu" my `<ul>` with the class "nav" appears, and when its clicked again, it toggles so that its not visible.

HTML

```
<div class="menu">
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Prices</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

JavaScript

```
$('line').click(function(){
    $('ul.nav').slideToggle();
})
```

Comment: google, "toggle class jquery" and you will find plenty of answers

Comment: `$('line')` should be `$('.line')`

Comment: Yep, anytime you use a class, you must use a period. Any time it's an id, use a #.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the tip. I am just starting out. Great

Comment: @mrwienerdog - but only for selectors . . . we don't want him toggling the class using `.toggleClass(".nav")`.   ;)

Answer (score 0):

To build off of `Ronnie`'s comment, you should probably use jQuery's `.toggleClass()` method, but you will also need to change how you are accessing the `<ul>`, because, once you remove the `nav` class, it will no longer be found with `$('ul.nav')`.

Try adding in an `id` attribute to that `<ul>` (I used "navMenu" below) and then using that to select the `<ul>`.  Then you can use `.toggleClass("nav")`, like this:

**HTML**

```
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="line"></div>
    </div>

    <ul id="navMenu" class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Prices</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(".line").click(function() {
    $("#navMenu").toggleClass("nav");
;})
```

**EDIT:** This assumes that the `<ul>` is not visible, by default (presumably using CSS) and that, by applying the "nav" class, it is made visible.